# Making a forward_list of a variadic template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, forward-list

I have a `std::forward_list` and a I have a class `Delegate` (taken from [here](http://blog.coldflake.com/posts/C++-delegates-on-steroids/)) that has is a class with a variadic type signature (`typename return_type, typename... Args`).

I want to make a `std::forward_list` out of these `Delegate`s. How would I go about doing so? I have tried:

`std::forward_list<Delegate<void, typename...> >` but it gives a syntax error. I would also like to add to this list later. I can guarantee that each of these lists (there will be multiple) will only have `Delegate` types that take the same number of parameters stored together. However, each list may have a list of methods that take different parameters than the methods in other lists.

These lists are actually going to be inside of a `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: starting to think this is impossible due to the way c++ compiles variadic templates

Comment: Could you please show a minimal example of code that fails to compile? (And the compile error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it sounds like you should use `unordered_multimap` instead of a map with lists as the values.

That said, if you're trying to store types in an STL container which differ even a little, you'll need to make a base class and store them as pointers to that base class.  You mentioned that all the values in one list will have the same number of parameters, but you didn't specify the parameters will be completely identical.

Comment: what is the difference between `unordered_map` and `unordered_multimap`

Comment: @KhanPower: essentially a multimap can store any number of values for one key, and it acts more or less like those values are stored in a list.  It's pretty similar to what you're describing, just simpler.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Could I iterate over those values inside the keys? I need to be able to iterate through them and call a method on all of them.

Comment: Ok thanks, I got it working by using void pointers and then casting.